# 2 colums inside a CSS grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, css-grid

I'm currently trying something new called CSS grid. Normally I use Bootstrap 4 to build my websites, but this time I thought let's learn something new. I tried by doing some basic stuff by adding a background color to the sections to know what's really happening

I have a section called 'main' and I would like to have 2 columns inside that section which one is positioned on the left side and the other one on the right side. I tried by adding a grid inside a grid, but that overlays everything which not works at all for me

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}
.section{
  grid-area: section;
}
.main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'section section';

  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.footer{
  grid-area: footer; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 500px 500px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    '. nav nav .'
    '. main main .'
    '. footer footer .';
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="grid-item nav">
    navigition
</nav>

<main class="grid-item main">
    <section class="grid-item section">
        1
    </section>
    <section class="grid-item section">
        2
    </section>
</main>

<footer class="grid-item footer">
    footer
</footer>

<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without "grid-area: section;". It makes what you want i think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that one area name cannot be used to describe more than one html element ? It would explain why you can assign two areas to the same item (. main main .) but you can't assign two different items ".section" to the same name section (it understands it like one unique element). I let you check [this W3C link](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_grid-area.asp) maybe :

*The grid-area property can also be used to assign a name to a grid item. Named grid items can then be referenced to by the grid-template-areas property of the grid container.*

But one solution to your problem could be, if it can help :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}
.main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* just describe that you want two columns*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.footer{
  grid-area: footer; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr; /*change this*/
  grid-template-areas:
    '. nav .'
    '. main .'
    '. footer .'; /*removing useless repetition*/
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="grid-item nav">
    navigition
</nav>

<main class="grid-item main">
    <section class="grid-item section">
        1
    </section>
    <section class="grid-item section">
        2
    </section>
</main>

<footer class="grid-item footer">
    footer
</footer>

<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
```